# How to enable trace in openssl cmp (openssl version 3 onwards)?

Tags: openssl, trace, pki

I want to enable trace level logging in openssl CMP CLI so as to print HTTP request/response header details.

I have tried the following but didn't get any success.

1. Built openssl with enabe-trace option. There is a Configure file which is used to create a make file and eventually make install to install openssl. Tried providing enable trace option while running the Configure file.

./config enable-trace

2. When (1) didn't work, I tried removing trace disabled option from the Configure file.
   There is a our%disabled section in the Configure file present in the openssl package which consists of default disabled utilities. This didn't work out as well.

Alongwith the above 2, verbosity level 8 i.e. trace was also passed in the CLI to print trace level logs but it ended up falling back to debug which is verbosity level 7.

**Edit : How to check whether trace has been enabled or not from CLI?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you are using the OpenSSL CMP command line application, or whether you are writing your own application that is using the OpenSSL CMP APIs.

Either way you need to enable "trace" at compile time as you did in (1) as a prerequisite. However that is not sufficient in itself.

If using the command line app then you should set the level of verbosity that you want using the `-verbosity` option. See the man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-cmp.html

If you are writing your own application then you need to use the trace APIs to setup the trace logging. Review the functions described on this page to set it up:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/OSSL_trace_set_channel.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are using CMP command line application and I did set the verbosity level to 8 which is for trace but it still falls back to debug every time.

The way I compiled it is just giving enable-trace option while running Configure file
./Configure enable-trace

Is this correct?

Comment: Also, please find the output of a sample IR in further comments.

openssl cmp -cmd ir -server localhost:80/pkix/ -recipient "/CN=CMPserver"  -secret pass:1234567890  -newkey nfkey.pem -subject "/CN=MyName"  -cacertsout capubs.pem -certout nfcert.pem -verbosity 8

(1/2)
setup_client_ctx:apps/cmp.c:1957:CMP info: will contact http://localhost:80/pkix/
CMP DEBUG: Starting new transaction with ID=A8:CB:9B:92:C2:D1:36:52:9B:21:9A:04:F1:91:90:88
CMP info: sending IR
CMP DEBUG: connecting to CMP server localhost:80
CMP DEBUG: finished reading response from CMP server
CMP info: received IP

Comment: (2/2)
CMP DEBUG: validating CMP message
......
CMP info: received PKICONF
CMP DEBUG: validating CMP message
CMP DEBUG: sucessfully validated PBM-based CMP message protection
save_free_certs:apps/cmp.c:2004:CMP info: received 1 enrolled certificate(s), saving to file 'nfcert.pem'

Comment: If you are seeing the DEBUG output then the tracing is working. Debug is verbosity level 7. Although in theory you can set the verbosity level all the way up to 8, I don't actually see any instances of logs being issued at the level in the OpenSSL source code. In other words you're already getting the maximum level of logging that you're going to get.

Comment: Okay. Actually, even without enabling trace and just by setting the verbosity level to 8  debug level logs are getting printed. Also, I see there are two files encoder_lib.c and decoder_lib.c which has trace logs. I am not sure how helpful they will be for our usecase though. We want to capture CMP HTTP request/response details with trace level logging.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL trace facility is pretty awkward to use and its use at CLI level so far is not prominently documented. Yesterday I had a hard time myself re-discovering how to make use of it at runtime (with some other OpenSSL app).

This is why I made sure that for the CMP functionality itself there is a different tracing option that is sufficiently documented and can be used easily without re-building: the `-verbosity <level>` option already mentioned above.

In order to trace the HTTP transfer (for CMP or any other OpenSSL app) at CLI level, you need to configure and build OpenSSL yourself with the `enable-trace` option ***and*** suitably set the `OPENSSL_TRACE` environment variable, for instance like this:

```
OPENSSL_TRACE=HTTP apps/openssl cmp
```

Note that I did document this, also specifically for CMP - see `man openssl-cmp`:

```
If OpenSSL was built with trace support enabled
and the environment variable OPENSSL_TRACE includes HTTP, 
the request and response headers of HTTP transfers are printed.
```

More general documentation is provided by `man openssl` (and also online, e.g. at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl.html):

```
 OPENSSL_TRACE=name[,...]
   Enable tracing output of OpenSSL library, by name.  This output will only make sense if you know OpenSSL internals well.
   Also, it might not give you any output at all if OpenSSL was built without tracing support.

   The value is a comma separated list of names, with the following available:
   ...
```